# CentOS: How to prevent a user from executing an application installed in a specific directory

Tags: security, permissions, centos, chmod, chown

I have an application installed in `/etc/mydir`.

I have executed the following to remove the ability for users to execute this program.

```
chown root:group1 /etc/mydir -R
chmod 700 /etc/mydir -R
```

I created a new user and logged in as this user. The new user was not added to `group1`
However, I was able to execute this program by just typing the program name.

How can I stop users being able to run this using `chmod` and `chown`. Please let me know.

PS. the new users cannot `cd` into `/etc/mydir` but they can still execute using the program name.

Comment: The executed program probably isn't actually in `/etc/mydir`. Try `which programname` and `type programname` (if bash is your shell) to determine what actually gets called when you type `programname`.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you! The alias to the program was actually pointing to a file in `/usr/libexec/mydir`. Once I ran `chown` and `chmod` on this folder, it worked as expected. I could have marked it as an answer if you typed it below. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's not too late for that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out what actually happens when you type the name of the program:

Use `which <programname>` to determine the location of the executable that gets executed when you type `<programname>`, which will be the first hit when trying the directories listed in the `PATH` environment in order. Use `echo $PATH` to find out where the shell looks for executables to run.

And just to be sure that your (`bash`) shell does not interfere, run `type <programname>` to find out whether aliases or functions are defined.

These will tell you that you're not actually running a program from the inaccessible directory, but from somewhere else.